# Can I detect how much bandwith a node Socket.IO client is using?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I had someone claim that my website is using a rather large amount of bandwith, and their Internet Provider is capping them or something of that sort.

Any idea on how I can get how much data the client is receiving and sending per second? I'd like to display the little usage stat somewhere it can be monitored (on the client's screen).

Thanks

Comment: ive experienced complaints like these and after sitting down in some of the locations they are using my product in that one certain routers don`t like streams ( I apologize for how un technical that analysis is ), also I have discovered that with certain types of data encrypting it or scrambling it has unexplainably sped it up hmmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is possible, I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mekwall/4458195). I tested it and it seems to work!

It is not specific to socket.io though, <strike>I could not find anything for that</strike> (ooooh I found [this](https://github.com/mrjoes/sock-benchmarking)) . But it looks like you could implement this into a emit function on server to count bytes sent. Good luck.

```
const net = require("net");

var server = net.createServer(function (c) {
    var oldWrite = c.write;
    c.write = function(d) {
            if (!Buffer.isBuffer(d)) {
                    d = new Buffer(d);
            }
            oldWrite.call(this, d);
            server.bytesSent += d.length;
    };

    c.on('data', function(d){
            server.bytesReceived += d.length;
    });

    c.write('Hello world!\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
    c.end();
});

server.bytesReceived = 0;
server.bytesSent = 0;

server.listen(3000);

var units = ["B", "kB", "MB", "TB"];
function simplifiedUnits(input) {
    var unit = units[0];
    var i = 0;
    while (input > 1024 && ++i) {
            unit = units[i];
            input /= 1024;
    }
    return Math.round(input) + " " + unit;
}

var time = process.hrtime();
setInterval(function (){
    process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');
    var diff = process.hrtime(time)[0] + process.hrtime(time)[1]/1000000000;
    var bpsSent = Math.round(server.bytesSent/diff) || 0;
    var bpsReceived = Math.round(server.bytesReceived/diff) || 0;
    console.log("Running node.js %s on %s-%s", process.version, process.platform, process.arch);
    console.log("Memory usage: %s", simplifiedUnits(process.memoryUsage().rss));
    console.log("Uptime: %ds", Math.round(process.uptime()));
    console.log("Open connections: %d", server.connections);
    console.log("In: %s (%s/s)", simplifiedUnits(server.bytesReceived), simplifiedUnits(bpsReceived));
    console.log("Out: %s (%s/s)", simplifiedUnits(server.bytesSent), simplifiedUnits(bpsSent));
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was looking for something specific to Socket.IO - Think Socket.IO stores bytes received/sent, so I could possibly adapt this to it?

Comment: Like stated, I have not found any info specific to Socket.io but this could be possible yes.

Comment: @Justin Updated the answer with a benchmarking tool I found specific for socket.io.